# Powershell, robocopy array: invalid parameter & timestamp preserving

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have this Powershell code:

```
Function CheckFileList()
{
    $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-270)
    $input_path = gci '//network/sourceDir' | sort -property LastWriteTime
    $output_file = 'c:\PowershellScripts\prune_results.txt'
    #Clear-Content $output_file
    $countf = 0
    $outputstr = ""

    $outputstr = $(Get-Date -format 'F') + " - Folders to be purged:`r`n"

    $input_path | Foreach-Object{
        if ( (Get-Item $_.FullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] ) {
            if ( $_.LastWriteTime -le $limit ) {
                $source='//network/sourceDir' + $_.Name
                $dest="\\computer\c$\targetDir" + $_.Name
                $what=@("/MOVE")
                $options=@("/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T")
                $cmdArgs = @("$source","$dest",$what,$options)
                #"robocopy " + $cmdArgs >> $output_file
                robocopy @cmdArgs
                $outputstr = $outputstr + " (" + $_.LastWriteTime + ") `t" + $_.Name + "`r`n"
                $countf++
                $outputstr = $outputstr + "Folders [to be] purged: " + $countf + "`r`n`r`n"
                $outputstr >> $output_file
                Exit
            }
        }
    }

    $outputstr = $outputstr + "Folders [to be] purged: " + $countf + "`r`n`r`n"
    $outputstr >> $output_file

}

CheckFilelist
```

This is intended to move many folders (and the files in them) while preserving the folder timestamps.

When I run it, I get this error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Apr 27 13:20:35 2015

   Source - \\network\sourceDir\someFolder12345\
     Dest - \\computer\c$\someFolder12345\

    Files :
  Options : /COPY:DAT /MOVE /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T"

       Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?


****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
```

Is there something wrong with my what/options array? The parameters look valid to me.

[EDIT] I'm also finding this script is not preserving folder timestamps. `someFolder12345` ends up on the targetDir with the date/time of "now". The files within the folder are preserving timestamps, but not the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your string `"/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T"` is being passed to robocopy as one argument, not as 2 separate arguments. If you check the `$options` variable, it has a single item in the array. Try changing that line to `$options=@("/COPY:DAT","/DCOPY:T")` so that each argument is passed in separately.

Comment: That seems to be it, makes sense. Running into an issue where timestamps aren't preserved as this is running

Comment: @JohnHubert, I am trying to copy Src files to a backup location and have the src files be named file + TimeStamp can you tell me what I am doing wrong in this line..? 
`Start /WAIT robocopy %EFM_TEMP% %EFM_BACKUP% *.CFX /S /NP /R:5 /W:5 /XX /MOV /LOG:%EFM_COPY_BACKUP%` do I need to add the `/TS` as the end..? I run this from a .bat file by the way